# getting the discord.py bot to echo a message and then remove it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

basically I want to make a bot that copy a message with a specific command and then remove the original message and keep its own. 
this is the code I used

```
if message.content.startswith("!echo"):
            await message.channel.send(message.content[5:].format(message))
            await client.delete_message(context.message)
```

so far the echoing works good but the original message doesn't get removed

Comment: What version of discord.py do you use? Because "client.delete_message" is outdated for the rewrite, if you are running the newest version, ```await message.delete()``` is the way to remove a message

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest discord.py library. You can check out your installed version with `python -m pip freeze`

In discord.py version 1.0 `.delete_message` was changed to `.delete`:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=delete#discord.Message.delete

To delete a message you do:

```
if message.content.startswith("!echo"):
  await message.channel.send(message.content[5:].format(message))
  await message.delete()
```

You can also do `await message.delete(delay=5)` if you wish to delete the message after 5 seconds.
Your bot needs to have the privilege of deleting messages in that text channel.